# Handle events for elements have preventDefault, stopPropagation or return false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I am building a Chrome extension and facing some event related problem.

My extension is to capture all the user's action on the browser, like user's click, type and etc.

I am using `document` to bind my events, for e.g.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

On some element, a `click` event is already added with a `return false;` statement, for e.g.

```
ele.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // some stuff

    return false;
})
```

Is there any way I can have my callback executed too, also for the cases where an `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.preventDefault()` added too.

Your help is appreciated.

PS: I know it is possible as [Ghost Inspector](https://ghostinspector.com/) have an extension for the same and it is working fine for these type of elements too.

Comment: `My extension is to capture all the user's action on the browser, like user's click, type and etc` that does not sound suspicious at all!

Comment: @H.B. Don't worry its a private extension will not be published on Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking into the element prototype, e.g.:

```
const listen = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function (e, h) {
    // Register own handler first.
    listen.call(this, e, h);
}
```

Make sure to execute this before anything else, of course.

Comment: I guess you missed the point that I don't have control of the website the event is already bound.

Comment: As far as i know extensions can inject scripts; so you can't inject the script as the first element in the head or something like that?

Comment: To make the answer complete you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: @wOxxOm I am using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` for the same.

Comment: executeScript is only one step, but your content script should further put the code into a script element or use other techniques shown in the topic I've linked.

Comment: @AshokVishwakarma: If you have a content script with `run_at: document_start`, it will execute before any other script.